# Help to understand japanese sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, meaning, words

> 私自身、自分の作ったものは先ほど書いたようにどんどん忘れていってしまうけれど、大好きで読みついできたよその作者の小説についてならば

1. 先ほどの意味？ → long time ago/just now?

   I tend to forget what I write just now/long time ago?
2. 私 → author?
3. What does よそ mean?

   読みついできたよそ → 読みついで/きた/よそ？
4. While reading =読みついで？

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think you can prevent your future questions from getting downvotes if you (1) ask one question per post, (2) include some research you've done to get an answer before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

先ほど書いたように is translated as "as I wrote earlier".

読みついできたよ/その作者の小説 means "I have read novels written by the author".

読みついできた/よその作者の小説 means "novels written by other authors which I have read". This seem to be correct according to your below comment.

読みつぐ means "    to read in succession".

Comment: 自分の作ったもの先ほど書いたようにどんどん忘れていってしまう->means novel that is written by me(?) i wrote the novel?読みついできたよ、その作者の小説について->another author's novel that i like(?)

Comment: I can't judge it by only this context but 自分の作ったもの is probably novels written by me because she(or he) say about novels written by the author in the following sentence.

Comment: 私自身、自分の作ったものは先ほど書いたようにどんどん忘れていってしまうけれど、大好きで読みついてきたよその作者の小説についてならば、どの頁にどんな言葉があって、登場人物の誰かどんな服をどんな場面で着ていて、どんな時に悲しんでどんな時に喜んだかということを、つぶさに見えているのです-> this means im an author(?) and also discussing another author novel(?) in the end he said that he remembered every detail of the novel of his favorite author (?)

Comment: And the first paragraph ここにある小説は、作者である「私」の手を離れて久しいものばかりです->つまり私は作者？

Comment: You had better add whole sentences and marshal your questions.

Comment: I really want to add whole sentences but its too long :/ anyway thankyou for your help!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think your understanding is correct.